# PDF generation using iText: with table on top of page and copy&paste text, text in table gets last

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext, pdfptable

We generate a PDF for incoming messages to our system using the iText Java library. It uses a table to display some meta data and a paragraph for the message body.

Now when we copy and paste the text of the pdf (in Acrobat Reader as well as Firefox PDF preview) into some editor, the meta data is pasted after the text on the first page.

Our code is basically

```
  final Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
  final PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
  pdfWriter.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.VERSION_1_2);
  document.open();
  final PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
  table.setWidthPercentage(100);
  table.addCell(newCell("New Message", true, FONT_SIZE_1, CELL_PADDING_1));
  document.add(table);
  document.add(new Paragraph(content, FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 10)));
  document.close();
  pdfWriter.close();
```

with

```
private static PdfPCell newCell(final String text) {
  final PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(
    new Phrase(new Chunk(text, FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 30))));
  cell.setPaddingTop(cellPadding);
  cell.setPaddingRight(0);
  cell.setPaddingBottom(8);
  cell.setPaddingLeft(0);
  cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
  return cell;
}
```

You can also see the phenomenon when you select text from page 1 and 2, suddenly the top of page 1 is also  selected, too. See this screenshot: [image: screenshot]

With copy & paste you get

```
 amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
 erat.
 New Message
 Message
 Message-No. 12345
 Label A Value X
 Label B Value Y
 Inhalt
 Consetetur sadipscing
```

You can also test it with this PDF: http://epischel.de/misc/testmessage.pdf

Comment: That's inherent to PDF. PDF isn't meant to copy/paste from. There is no answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. A workaround is to make everything a table, i.e. putting the message body in a one or more table cells.

Comment: Such behavior is fairly common in PDFs; funny text selections just like funny orders in which search results are found and shown.

Comment: BTW, your sample document mostly consists of 0 bytes.